# How to decode image roi with tensor flow?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tensorflow

After I detect image from the face after detecting with haarcasde file.
But I am getting this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_string_ops.py in substr(input, pos, len, unit, name)
   1888       _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
   1889         _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "Substr", name,
-> 1890         tld.op_callbacks, input, pos, len, "unit", unit)
   1891       return _result
   1892     except _core._FallbackException:

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

Here's my code

```
def detect_and_noise_face(img):

    # Watch solutions video for line by line explanation!

    face_img = img.copy()
    roi = img.copy()

    face_rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(face_img,scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=3) 
    for (x,y,w,h) in face_rects: 

        roi = roi[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        image = tf.image.decode_image(roi)

    return face_img
```

why am I decoding image because I am trying to create adversarial example on that roi.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/adversarial_fgsm
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.image.decode_image` is used to decode raw input bytes into a tensor, which is not the case here.

I guess that what you want is to convert a numpy array (`roi`) into a `tf.Tensor`. For that, you can just use `tf.convert_to_tensor` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor